# AWS - Como fazer CRUD no S3

Tags: amazon-aws, crud, request

Recentemente comecei a estudar AWS, e estou me sentindo totalmente perdido em relação ao significado de algumas coisas, como elas funcionam e qual são seus contextos para a aplicação.

Por exemplo 
Chaves (keys), baldes (bucket),ARN ... Coisas do tipo.

Alguém poderia me dizer o significado delas e me exemplificar algumas operações CRUD diretamente dentro do AWS S3 ?

Com o código abaixo eu consigo logar e copiar as coisas da caixa de entrada (inbox) até a caixa de saida (outbox) mas nada mais que isso.

```
public class FileBatch
{

    private readonly string[] _supportedImageTypes = new string[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
    private readonly AmazonS3Client _s3Client;

    public FileBatch()
    {
        AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();



        _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
            "00000000000000000000", //ID_Access
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", //Key_Access
            config
        );


    }

    public async Task OcrHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext context)
    {


 foreach (var record in s3Event.Records)
        {

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(record.S3.Object.Key, @"inbox/.*"))
            {
                continue;
            }

Console.WriteLine(
                $"A imagem '{record.S3.Bucket.Name}:{record.S3.Object.Key}' será processada e copiada para a caixa de saída");

            var outputKey = record.S3.Object.Key.Replace("inbox/", "outbox/");

            CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest
            {
                SourceBucket = record.S3.Bucket.Name,
                SourceKey = record.S3.Object.Key,
                DestinationBucket = record.S3.Bucket.Name,
                DestinationKey = outputKey
            };
            CopyObjectResponse response = await _s3Client.CopyObjectAsync(request);

        }
    }
```

Acho que acabei descobrindo a documentação que eu precisava para fazer as operações mais simples, porém não sei utilizar direito...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client.htm

---

Acredito que essa seja a maneira de criar as coisas dentro das pastas do AWS

```
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

// Create a PutObject request
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = "SampleBucket",
    Key = "Item1",
};

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("contents.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    request.InputStream = stream;

    // Put object
    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta para sua pergunta não é tão simples e pode causar uma discussão extensa sobre como melhor modelar/design/projetar uma solução de software para utilizar uma estrutura de armazenamentos de objetos (e.g. AWS S3, AWS Glazier).  Portanto a seguir é a minha interpretação de como você poderia seguir seu desenvolvimento revisitando alguns conceitos e julgando o melhor para o seu cenário.

O [AWS S3 é uma solução de software para armazenamento de objetos da AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/what-is-cloud-object-storage/), que utiliza conceitos específicos da AWS por ser uma soluções proprietária da AWS.

Banco de dados relacionais (e.g. Oracle DB, Mysql DB) modelam seus dados utilizando conceitos de tabelas e relacionamentos.

De acordo com o Wikipedia em português [CRUD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) significa:

> CRUD (acrónimo do inglês Create, Read, Update e Delete) são as quatro
>   operações básicas (criação, consulta, atualização e destruição de
>   dados) utilizadas em bases de dados relacionais (RDBMS) fornecidas aos
>   utilizadores do sistema.

A versão em inglês tem uma discussão mais interessante sobre REST ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete ), S3 implementa uma api em REST que pode ser [interpretada](https://www.cloudatomiclab.com/post-crud/) como CRUD.

Seguindo as definições em português, CRUD originalmente é utilizado como solução de software para acessar dados dentro de base de dados relacional.

Entretanto S3 não é relacional. Eventualmente você poderia utilizar uma abordagem CRUD com o S3, entretanto existem [alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632439/is-cqrs-alternative-to-crud) de abstração mais ricas.

Sobre as possibilidades do que pode fazer com o S3, a documentação da AWS é extensa e de excelente qualidade, sugiro que inicie por https://aws.amazon.com/pt/s3/getting-started/